# How do you add a key/value pair to a lodash _pick method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```
user = new User({
        email: value.email,
        firstName: value.firstName,
        lastName: value.lastName,
        password: value.password,
        isAdmin: value.isAdmin,
        ipAddress: req.ip,
        userAgent: req.get('user-agent')
});

console.log(_.pick(value, ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'isAdmin']));
```

I want to add the following key/value pairs -- ipAddress:req.ip and userAgent:req.get('user-agent') -- to the _.pick return, but cannot figure out how to do this.

I'm able to do it this way:

```
let o = _.pick(value, ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'isAdmin']);
o["ipAddress"] = req.ip;
o["userAgent"] = req.get('user-agent');
console.log(o);
```

... but I'm curious is there's a way to do it in the same console.log line.

Comment: you can't - you already assigned away the values into the object passed to the `User` constructor.

Comment: let o = _.pick(value, ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'isAdmin']);
        o["ipAddress"] = req.ip;
        o["userAgent"] = req.get('user-agent');
        console.log(o);

Comment: I was wondering if it could be one on the same line though.

Comment: The question is why are you extracting the variables and then using _.pick again?  You only have to do the property extraction once, which is exactly the same data that your console.log needs.  And there's easier ways to destructure or use shorthands to make your syntax more concise.  You're basically doing an inverse code golf here, where by definition you are undoing DRY.  Very straightforward short solution is to just assign it to a variable.

Comment: If you really _must_ try to put it on one line and re-extract it:  `console.log({ ipAddress: req.ip, userAgent: req.get('user-agent'), ..._.pick(value, ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'isAdmin']) })`.  or `console.log(_.pick({ ...value, ipAddress: req.ip, userAgent: req.get('user-agent')}, ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'isAdmin', 'ipAddress', 'userAgent']))`  Honestly I don't know why you would want to write it like this rather than just using variables normally.